# error in installing Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, nuget

I am trying to install Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR from NuGet and get the following error:

> 'Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.0.2'. You are trying to install this
>   package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but
>   the package does not contain any assembly references or content files
>   that are compatible with that framework. For more information, conta
>   ct the package author.

Has anyone encountered this, and knows what the solution is?

Answer (score 5):

SignalR 2.0 does not support .net 4.0. Either do a upgrade of .net or use a 1.x version of SignalR.

```
>Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.1.3
```

[source](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1723)

Comment: i did that also,but signalr hub is not visible

Comment: not visible? I'd appreciate if you could elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is upgrading from Framework 4.0 to Framework 4.5.

Go to the "WEBSITE > Start Options" in the Visual Studio menu, and then change your "Target Framework" to 4.5.

Also make sure that controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion (if used) is also 4.5 in your web.config.

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.5" />
  </system.web>
```