# How to install Owin

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget, owin

I'm try to install owin.security on my asp.net mvc 4 application from here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin.Security.Providers/ , but have an error:

```
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.0.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, 
contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Owin.Security.Providers
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
```

I was try to search in google, but found information only about SignalR. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Your .Net Version does not Match for the required version for owin.security. Try change your project framework target?

Comment: @Tareffic I have .Net 4 version. For what version I should change?

Comment: I've answered below. SignalR 2.0 does not support .net 4.0.

Comment: You'll need dotnet Framework 4.5, not 4.0

Comment: In that case go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935(v=vs.110).aspx and step over to .net 4.5

Comment: Updating the project to target .NET 4.5 is the correct answer. If you look at the Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.0.2 NuGet package using NuGet Package Explorer you can see it only includes assemblies for .NET 4.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm very surprised. I searched for system requirements for *Microsoft OWIN* aka *Katana*. I had a hard time finding a definitive answer on this as well.

So when in doubt, head to the source:

https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security/Microsoft.Owin.Security.csproj

According to the project file:

```xml
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

That is why NuGet won't let you install the package. You need to update your project to .NET 4.5 Framework.

Comment: But I cant update, because use external libraries which according to 4.0 framework. Is this any way instead of upgrading?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so. I imagine Microsoft is using new APIs that are only available in 4.5. As for your application, 4.5 is backward compatible, so it can still use 3rd party libraries that were written for 4.0. Have you tried creating a test app in 4.5 and see if your external library works properly? Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with an existing project that I am working on, try this

`Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb -Version 2.1.0`

better to install a little older version of `Owin`, because `.NET framework 4.0` doesn't support newer versions. But you will get almost all the features.

Answer (score 3):

SignalR 2.0 does not support .net 4.0. Either do a upgrade of .net or use a 1.x version of SignalR.

```
>Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.1.3
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680897/error-in-installing-package-microsoft-aspnet-signalr)

Comment: But I'm didn't need SignalR, I need Owin.

Comment: I hope someone else can answer this for you. Goodluck

Comment: I added the v1 of SignalR as I need it for my app, but it only installs OWIN for .Net 4.5, which then hoses the app. I have yet to find a work around.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error during installing Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.0.2.After that, i have changed my .net framework from 4.0 to 4.5 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had just pulled an existing project into my solution and was getting the error. One project was at 4.5 and the other was at 4.51. Putting them at the same framework release solved the problem.